# Polyglot, XHTML5, dl,dt,dd how to make a space between entries?

Tags: html, polyglot-markup

I have this piece of Polyglot XHTML5 and I am trying to make a space between each reference.
However it seems I cannot use the `p` or `br` tags. It still has to be valid...

Hopefully somebody could help out, would be super awesome!

```
<dl class="references">
    <dt id="ref-abc">[abc2007]</dt>
    <dd>Herpa Derp; <em>Trollolol</em>;
        Elolololol
        <a href="http://example.com">
        <code>http://www.example.com</code>
        </a>
    </dd>
    <dt id="ref-abc">[abc2007]</dt>
    <dd>Herpa Derp; <em>Trollolol</em>;
        Elolololol
        <a href="http://example.com">
        <code>http://www.example.com</code>
        </a>
    </dd>
    <dt id="ref-abc">[abc2007]</dt>
    <dd>Herpa Derp; <em>Trollolol</em>;
        Elolololol
        <a href="http://example.com">
        <code>http://www.example.com</code>
        </a>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Why can't you use `p` or `br` tags (like a simple `<br/>` after your anchor)? They should be valid in polyglot-markup (as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use CSS to get the space between the definitions:

```
.references dd { margin-bottom:16px; }
```